# How to make a discord bot so that it can send notifications from a website to a certain channel Python

Tags: python, discord

▲
I have a question how to make my bot can send notifications from Google Classroom to my discord on a certain channel?
I don't know how to do it

Comment: maybe use web scrapper to do it . for example bs4

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/) to fetch your notifications from the [notifications endpoint](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/push-notifications), and send it as a discord `Message`  object to your desired channel.